# Is there a way to test HTML5 canvas performance?

Tags: performance, html5-canvas

At the moment I know how to get information such as the Frames per second (FPS) and the amount of time it took to render the last frame (in MS).

I would like to get more information, it could be anything, but more information on memory usage and such would be great.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT-PRECISION: I would need to get this information from the code! (JavaScript); And from any browser, or as many as possible.**

**EDIT: I am still looking for more information such as memory usage and such. c:**

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Using the build-in profiling tools

When you use **Firefox**, there is the very powerful [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) addon which includes a Javascript debugger and a profiler.

The developer tools of **Chrome**, including a Profiler, can be enabled with Ctrl+Shift+I or from the menu in Tools->Developer Tools.

The Javascript debugger and profiler of **Internet Explorer** can be reached by pressing F12.

### Implementing your own profiling code

When you want to implement your own performance profiling code in Javascript, you can use the `performance.now()` function at strategic places of your code. This will return the current time in milliseconds as a floating-point number (The actual accuracy varies from browser to browser and plattform to plattform). Compare it to an earlier measurement to see how long the code between two calls took to execute.

```
var before = performance.now();
veryExpensiveFunction();
var after = performance.now();
console.log("veryExpensiveFunction took " + (after - before) + "ms to execute.");
```

The performance.now() function is a rather new and non-standard feature, but according to [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now%28%29) it is supported by the most recent versions of most common browsers. For greater compatibility, you can use the less precise `Date.now()` or `new Date().getTime()`. It also returns the time in milliseconds, but only returns an integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will certainly note this! PS: I wish I could upvote you, but I can't since I need 15 rep to do so. :c

Comment: @Pheelbert When you like my answer best, you can accept it by clicking the tick-icon next to it.

Comment: To support older browser just rewrite: `var before = performance ? performance.now() || new Date().getTime();`

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 and go to the profiler and record a profile as you load a page. This will tell you how long time spent in each function. Pretty helpful.

Comment: I would need to get this information code-wise, sorry for not precising. I will be adding this to my question! Still interesting, thanks.